# What is the exactly meaning of "In_use" from "SHOW OPEN TABLES" command in mysql

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

`In_use` column from `SHOW OPEN TABLES` command in mysql is locking count as far as I know.

But, After many times of reading data from table, `In_use` value has been increased.

And all records of updating to that table is available.

What is the exactly meaning of `In_use`?

I've tested on MySQL 5.6 Community Server (Amazon RDS) with Default configurations and InnoDB.

Comment: In_use does not mean that the table is eXclusively locked.  It _may_ refer to "any" lock.  It does indicate how many connections are currently working with that table.  Complex selects (with `UNION` and/or subqueries) _may_ increment the counter more than once.  (I don't know.)  Why do you care about `In_use`?  (I have not found much use for it.)

Comment: And note that  HANDLER ... OPEN statements increase that variable and HANDLER... CLOSE can decrease the value.